# Woocommerce Wordpress Create category for "Out of Stock" items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories

Is there a way to create a category for items that have their quantity/inventory set to '0'? So that all these items can appear on their own page?

I need to display all "Sold" products, and I don't think it makes sense to create a "Sold" category to add them to, as this starts to get funky with how to items are categorized within other product categories.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a plugin that works, for anyone else who may need it:

> [**WooCommerce Sold Out Products**](http://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-sold-out-products/) enhances the built-in WooCommerce functionality by adding a Widget and Shortcode for displaying sold out products.

Comment: Can we view it somewhere online?